# How to display a Google Map on Worklight App

Tags: javascript, google-maps, ibm-mobilefirst

I have the following files in Worklight. I want to load the map on the worklight app. It is visible in the "Design" view but neither on simulator nor on emulator. Kindly help.

```
//index.html
<div id="pagePort"></div>


//page1.html
<script src="js/page1.js"></script>
<div id="content">
<button type="button" onclick="loadPage5();">Click</button>
</div>


//page1.js
function loadPage5()
{
var pagepath="page5.html";
pagesHistory.push("page1.html");
$("#pagePort").load(pagepath,function(){WL.Logger.info("Page Loaded");});
}


//page5.html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<body>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<script src="js/page5.js"></script>
<script src="js/page1.js"></script>
<script src="js/initOptions.js"></script> 
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<script src="js/messages.js"></script> 
</body>


//page5.js

function initialize() {
var myLatlng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(28.5084805,77.2272778);
var mapOptions = {
zoom: 11,
center: myLatlng1
}
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
position: myLatlng1,
map: map,
});
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Major revision to the answer based on the comments and edits made to the question*

See the following Worklight 6.1.0.1 sample project, that demonstrates page navigation and loading of Google Maps in another page in the app.

This sample is based on the same multi-page sample provided by IBM, that your code snippets above are based on:

- [Multi-page application with Google Maps](https://www.dropbox.com/s/htsrrlb5yaglwgl/MultiPagesWithGMaps.zip)

Tesed in Worklight Console preview as well as iOS Simulator.

Comment: The map is getting displayed as I move to the next page, only problem is how to "center" the "value" selected from first page.

Comment: Again, your HTML may work, but your Worklight app will not. If you try to invoke a adapter, use Cordova or any Worklight API, it will not work. First fix that, then worry about centering a map

Comment: I changed the coding, and I am NOT using any JavaScript Library(JQuery or Dojo). I am working on Worklight without any library. The map is getting diplayed in the "Design" view, but neither on simulator nor on emulator. Please help.

Comment: Didn't I say this will happen? If you navigate away from the main HTML like you do in your code snippets, the Worklight framework is LOST, thus, it will FAIL. Please, read the documentation and make your app follow what Worklight guides say - and *then* worry about your map. If you want further help, provide the WHOLE Worklight project.

Comment: This is how I have done the coding:

On index.html
<div id="pagePort"></div>

On page1.html  
<button type="button" onclick="loadPage5();">Click</button>

On page5.html
The same map code given above

On page1.js
function loadPage5()
{
    var pagepath="page5.html";
    pagesHistory.push("page1.html");
    $("#pagePort").load(pagepath,function(){WL.Logger.info("Page Loaded");});
}

Comment: @user3283577, if my answer helped resolve your problem, please mark as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Better separate the `Javascript` from the `index.html` file and then follow the below steps.

You can simply pass the `value` on `onchange` event like

```
<select onchange="initialize(" + this.value + ")">
```

Then

```
function initialize(value) { // process the value
  var myLatlng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(28.5084805,77.2272778);
  var myLatlng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(28.6473116,77.1559846);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 11,
    switch(value){
     case "south": center: myLatlng1; break;
     case "west": center: myLatlng2; break;
    }
}
```