# how to access google map in ios environment

Tags: ios, google-maps, ibm-mobilefirst

In My Worklight hybrid sample application I want google map in I phone (IOS) environment.I am using worklight 7.1, Jquery Mobile 1.4.5

I've done it in android environment but i am not able to seeing map in iphone.

My JS code:

```
var x=document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation()
  {
  if(navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position); 
  }
  else{x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
  }
function showPosition(position)
  {
  x.innerHTML="Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;    
}
```

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>HTMLGeoLocation</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
            <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/HTMLGeoLocation.css">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
            <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>
        </head>
        <body id="content" style="display: none;">
            <!--application UI goes here-->
            <p id="demo">Click the button to get your coordinates:</p>
<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>
            <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
            <script src="js/HTMLGeoLocation.js"></script>
            <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
        </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many examples online demonstrating integration of Google Maps in Web apps, including those that use the Worklight client framework.

It is unclear what is your Worklight version, so here are some links you can explore. These also provide sample projects for you to review their implementation and run them locally.

- [How to display a Google Map on Worklight App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22684553/how-to-display-a-google-map-on-worklight-app)
- https://www.dropbox.com/s/vozn1hcbs2fb70g/GoogleMapsInWorklight.zip

Comment: I have fixed the broken link.

Comment: in second link sample project don't have iphone environment ,i added iphone environment and Idan any thing I want to add permission/features in iphone config.xml file

Comment: You do not need to touch config.xml